# C++ reference and dereference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a question for you.

```
void static splitArray(int *A, int size, int ind1, int ind2, int *&first, int &firstSize, int *&second, int &secondSize)
{
    firstSize = ind2 - ind1 + 1;
    secondSize = size - firstSize;
    first = new int[firstSize];
    second = new int[secondSize];
    int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){ 
        if ((i >= ind1) && (i <= ind2)){
            first[cnt1] = A[i];
            cnt1++;
        } 
        else {
            second[cnt2] = A[i];
            cnt2++;
        }
    }
```

This function is to a split the input array between given number indices in the parameter, and combines the remainings and fills the arrays in the parameters. But in the parameters, reference and dereferance operators used together. (*&) Was'nt it supposed to neutralise each other? How does it work? Can you please help me?

Comment: Those aren't operators at all. They're part of the *type*.

Comment: That's a reference to pointer. It means the pointer is going to be passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simple example

```
int x;
int &rx = x;

int *p;
int * &rp = p;
```

Declaration

```
int *&first
```

is a declaration of a reference to an object of type `int *`

In the body of the functipn variables first and second are changed.

```
first = new int[firstSize];
second = new int[secondSize];
```

As they are references to the arguments then these changes will be done in fact to with the original objects that were passed to the function as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is the reference of a pointer to an int is passed to the function.

Take a step back, if you only pass the 'pointer to an int' to a function, once inside the function, you can change what the pointer is pointing to (i.e. you can change the memory location of where the pointer is pointing *to*).

In this case since you pass a reference to a pointer to an int (think of it like another level of indirect, i.e. the level of indirect here is equivalent to the level of indirect as if you have a pointer to a pointer to an int), you can actually change the memory location *of* the pointer itself.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks odd, but can make some code look simpler.  Consider two equivalent ways of creating an array:

```
void array_byref(int*& p)
{
  p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
  p[0] = 0;
  p[1] = 1;
  p[2] = 2;
}

void array_byptr(int** p)
{
  *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
  (*p)[0] = 0;
  (*p)[1] = 1;
  (*p)[2] = 2;
}
```

The top example looks neater than the lower one because it combiners pointers and references.
But I haven't really seen the use "in the wild" much, so I don't think it's common or good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` and `&` characters do two things:

1. they *declare* pointer and reference types

   ```
   int i = 7;   // this is just an int
   int *p;      // this is a pointer-to-int
   int &r = i;  // this is a reference-to-int;
   ```
2. and they *operate* to dereference pointers and take the addresses of objects (respectively)

   ```
   int i = *p; // dereference pointer-to-int p (and get an integer value)
   p = &i;     // take the address of int i (and get a pointer-to-int)
   ```

---

We can show them all in some actual code:

```
// the function header is declaring the arguments,
// so here * and & are part of the type
int foo(int i,    // i is an int
        int *p,   // p is a pointer-to-int
        int &r,   // r is a reference-to-int
        int *&rp  // rp is a reference to a pointer-to-int
        )
{
    // the function body is executing statements,
    // so * and & here mean the operators
    *p = i; // operator* dereferences pointer p,
            // then we store the value of i at that address
    r = i;  // references do this automatically
    rp = p; // we just changed the caller's pointer-to-int,
            // via the reference, so it points to the same int as p
    p = &i; // then we used operator& to take the address of i, and
            // point our local copy of pointer-to-int p there

    // one last declaration, for old time's sake
    int &l = *p; // a reference to the integer p points at
    return l;
}
```

You can run this to see the effects:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   const int c = 42;
   int i = 7;
   int *in = &i;
   int **out = 0;

   int result = foo(c, in, i, out);
   cout << "c   = " << c << endl;
   cout << "i   = " << i << endl;
   cout << "in  = " << in << ", *in = " << *in << endl;
   cout << "out = " << out << ", *out = " << *out << endl;
}
```